Is there a way to disable automatic icon adjustment when switching to dark mode in iOS18?
Starting with iOS 18, the color of app icons will be automatically adjusted when you switch to dark mode. However, we do not want to provide icons for dark mode (this is due to various reasons. Please consider this as a premise).
How can I keep displaying the same icons as in light mode even when switching to dark mode?
Can you disable the auto-adjust app icons feature?
https://developer.apple.com/jp/design/human-interface-guidelines/dark-mode#Icons-and-images
The documentation does say that it's possible to do this, but the description in Apple's documentation is too abstract for me to understand.
